# How to test if your REST API service supports gzip data?

Tags: gzip, gatling

I am testing a REST API service that supports json and gzip data. I have tested the response from the json request payload. How to test if it handles gzip data properly? Please help?

Basically the client sends a request with accept-encoding as gzip in the header, service handles the compression and the client takes care of the decompression. But I need a way to confirm that service indeed handles compressed gzip data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip is basically a header + deflate + a **checksum**.

Gatling will retain the original `Content-Encoding` response header so you can check if the payload was gzipped, and then trust the gzip codec to do the checksum verification and throw an error if the payload was malformed.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to pass the "Accept-encoding" in the request header with value of gzip and verify the response has a header "content-encoding" with a value of gzip.This happens only when the service supports gzip compression. If the service does not handle gzip, then the response does not have the content-encoding header.